# Branch.io deep link webhook: event contents between test and live mode are different

Tags: webhooks, deep-linking, branch.io, referrals

I am trying to add referral functionality using branch.io deep link with a web hook. So, I’ve created the web hook by following the documentation (https://docs.branch.io/apps/deep-linking-api/#webhook-create) and set up the server to listen branch events. Everything was OK until testing in a production context.

Indeed, my problem is that branch sends shorter events in live mode than in test mode. Above, you can see a sample event triggered in debug and then the same event triggered in release.

```
{
    "metadata": {
        some metadata
    },
    "os": "Android",
    "os_version": "28",
    "first_referring_click_timestamp": "2019-11-18T16:27:19.708Z",
    "session_referring_identity": "referrer identity here",
    "event_timestamp": "2019-11-18T16:27:28.069Z",
    "ad_tracking_enabled": "false",
    "first_referring_identity": "referrer identity here",
    "session_referring_click_timestamp": "2019-11-18T16:27:19.708Z",
    "identity": "new user identity here",
    "session_referring_click_id": 725011506093376000,
    "first_referring_link_data": {
        "date_ms": 1574093470987,
        "date_sec": 1574093470,
        "date": "2019-11-18T16:11:10.987Z",
        "data": {
            "$og_title": "My title",
            "$publicly_indexable": "false",
            "~creation_source": 2,
            "$og_description": "My description",
            "source": "android",
            "$identity_id": "705413318433314220",
            "~stage": "new referral link",
            "$og_image_url": "http://www.lorempixel.com/400/400/",
            "~feature": "sharing",
            "+url": "the referral link",
            "$one_time_use": false,
            "~id": "725007442983731359",
            "~campaign": "referral",
            "~channel": "referral"
        },
        "feature": "sharing",
        "stage": "new referral link",
        "branch_id": "725007442983731359",
        "channel": "referral",
        "campaign": "referral",
        "state": 1
    },
    "event": "test_sign-up",
    "session_referring_link_data": {
        "date_ms": 1574093470987,
        "date_sec": 1574093470,
        "date": "2019-11-18T16:11:10.987Z",
        "data": {
            "$og_title": "My title",
            "$publicly_indexable": "false",
            "~creation_source": 2,
            "$og_description": "My description",
            "source": "android",
            "$identity_id": "705413318433314220",
            "~stage": "new referral link",
            "$og_image_url": "http://www.lorempixel.com/400/400/",
            "~feature": "sharing",
            "+url": "the referral link",
            "$one_time_use": false,
            "~id": "725007442983731359",
            "~campaign": "referral",
            "~channel": "referral"
        },
        "feature": "sharing",
        "stage": "new referral link",
        "branch_id": "725007442983731359",
        "channel": "referral",
        "campaign": "referral",
        "state": 1
    }
}
```

Event in live mode

```
{ 
    metadata: { some metadata},
    os: 'Android',
    identity: 'new user identity',
    google_advertising_id: 'google id',
    os_version: '28',
    event: 'test_sign-up',
    event_timestamp: '2019-11-26T11:33:24.321Z',
    hardware_id: 'google id',
    ad_tracking_enabled: 'true' 
}
```

So, my question is, how can I have at least the “session_referring_identity” field in live mode?

For information, events are sent from a native Android application and links are test links for test mode and live links for live mode. Furthermore, the referral link contains the identity of the referrer, e.g. if I use the REST API, I can retrieve the identity of the user which has generated the deep link.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For those having the same issue, here is the response from the branch.io support service :

> Sorry to say that we stop supporting "type=web_hook" for the referral rules. Because of this, please use the "type=credit" for the referral rules, once you create the new rule, you can find the rules under Referral Rules page in the dashboard.